Expo go 23.1 update causing Failed to parse manifest error
Yesterday expo go updated to version 23.1. NOthing changed on my app. its a react native project using expo. I went to launch the app on my iphone with expo go and Im getting an error stating
there was a problem running the app. failed to parse manifest. 
the operation couldn't be completed. (exupdates.updateerror error 1.)

How to fix this?
This is only happening when trying to open the app through expo go on my iphone. I can load the app just fine using a simulator through Xcode.

I was having the same issue and the following steps seemed to work for me.
For starters I made sure I had the latest version of expo (v51)
npm install -g expo-cli@latest

I then removed my node_modules and package-lock.json file
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json

I then ran
npm install --legacy-peer-deps

Note: I was having an issue with @react-navigation/stack and its dependency react-native-gesture-handler, the following line had me back up and running. I mention this because you may have a similar issue with a difference dependency.
npm install react-native-gesture-handler --legacy-peer-deps

Running npx expo start -c had me back up and running. Good luck

Does your project have expo 51? Mine has expo 49

This worked for me! Although on mac I had to use sudo npm install in the second command.

@KingJoeffrey Yes I installed the latest version of expo. In my package.json I just replaced the version to: {  "expo": "~51.0.2"  } and then ran the npm install.

I also had issues with the react-navigation-stack and icons. So i had to remove these dependencies and other that where breaking the app,
remove node_modules and package-lock.json

then:
npm install
npx expo-doctor
npx expo install --check
npx expo install --fix


One reason for this might be you start the app with
expo start

Starting it with the following command resolved my problem.
npx expo start


The release notes of Expo SDK 51 discuss the situation with Expo Go and how to work with older versions of the SDK.  It specifically mentions that the updated Expo Go in the AppStore no longer supports SDK 49 and SDK 50, and how to deal with that.

You will have to Upgrade Your Projects To Expo 51. My Expo Go app also got updated overnight. I tried Installing latest Expo Version in my project with:
npm install -g expo-cli@latest

but somehow it was still not working so I downloaded a downgraded Expo Go SDK 50 from Expo's Site : https://expo.dev/go

We have to update our projects to expo 51…
https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/s/VVEuuPyl7o
